# navigate "forwards" to the previous route with vue-router

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

In my Vue 2.7 app I'm using Vue Router 3.6.5 for navigation. Say I navigate from page foo to bar, when I click a button on page bar, I want navigation to transition to whatever page I was on previously (foo in this example).

I know I can navigate **back** to the previous page with `$router.back()` or `$router.go(-1)`, but this moves backwards to a previous point in the browser's history, i.e. the browser's forward button will be enabled if I navigate like this.

What I want to do is navigate "forwards" to the previous route, i.e. as though the user had clicked on a link to that route, rather than navigating to it via the back button.

In other words, if the current navigation history is

1. foo
2. bar (current page)

I want to navigate to foo such that the new history will be

1. foo
2. bar
3. foo (current page)

Comment: Did you tried `$router.go(1)`?

Comment: @kissu I don't think that will work, because it will (try to) go forward in the navigation history, but at the point where I'm on bar, I'm already at the latest route.

Comment: If you go back, you still can go forward I think.

Comment: @kissu but I haven't gone back. Maybe you need to re-read the question (or I need to explain it better)?